# Read Google Calendar API Push Notification in PHP

Tags: php, notifications, google-calendar-api

I have successfully configured Google API Calendar Event Change Push Notifications.  My notification page gets called as it should be when I set up the notification or change the calendar.

BUT...being a bit of a PHP dunce I don't understand how to see the content of the notification.

SO (MAIN QUESTION)...how do I get at the variables in the notification?  The notification calls my designated page.  What are the variables?  How are they sent?  How are they organized?

There is the larger question of how one should determine the content of a call to a page in PHP.  I tried all manner of var_dump, print_r, etc.  All I get with:

```
<?php
$arr = get_defined_vars();
error_log(print_r($arr),0);
?>
```

is:  1  Yes, just the number 1 in my error_log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I read the respose is:

```
$content = apache_request_headers();
```

If you print $content the data is self explenatory. However; for more information hwo to read the header check the link below:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#receiving

Comment: There you go!  Thanks.  Final display of the array was done with:     $content = apache_request_headers();
error_log("Notification Page: ".print_r($content, TRUE),0);

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks this sucks big time. IF only they could send back the ID of the event which changed... This would be so much better...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. it's working. i wrote to file.

```
    $content = apache_request_headers();
    get_contents($content);
    function get_contents($result) {
        $fp = fopen('config.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($result));
        fclose($fp);
    }
```